# jQuery: binding a single event listener that can handle events of its children

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, event-bubbling

I encountered a question to which I didn't know the solution for.

Suppose I have this HTML markup (dynamically generated by the server or simply a static file):

```
<ul class="myList">
<li><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
<li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
<li><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
<li><a href="page4.html">Page 4</a></li>
<li><a href="page5.html">Page 5</a></li>
<li><a href="page6.html">Page 6</a></li>
<!-- ... -->
<li><a href="page1000.html">Page 1000</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to bind a click event handler to the <a> tag.  Normally, I would write out

```
$('.myList').find('a').click(function() {});  /* Or something similar */
```

which would perform implicit iteration on all the anchor tags to bind a click event to each of them.  However, I was told that this is an expensive operation.

I was asked if there was some way to attach only one event listener (on the ul tag) and use event bubbling to figure out which anchor tag was clicked.  I have never encountered something like this, so I didn't know the answer.  Apparently, there is an answer.  Does anybody know how to place a single event listener on an element and have it figure out which child element was clicked?  (I still need to use event.preventDefault() to prevent the default click event.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) — it's exactly what you're asking for.

```
$('ul.mylist').delegate('a', 'click', function() {
  // ... your code ...
});
```

You get all the benefits of a jQuery handler, without having to do the binding to all those elements.

Answer (score 4):

You can access `event.target`, which will be the element that started the event.

```
$('.myList').click(function(event) {
   var target = $(event.target);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/h6SJh/).

However, [Pointy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209304/jquery-binding-a-single-event-listener-that-can-handle-events-of-its-children/6209316#6209316) seems to be easier to use.

Comment: Also, useful to know, but I agree with you that .delegate() is easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a version of jQuery >= 1.7 the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method supplants [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). In both jQuery [2.x](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js) and [1.11](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js) `.delegate()` simply calls `.on()`:

```
delegate: function( selector, types, data, fn ) {
        return this.on( types, selector, data, fn );
}
```

To use it in this case:

```
$(".myList li a").on("click", function(e) {
  //Code here, and you can use e.preventDefault(); to avoid the default event.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you attach will have an event parameter that contains the object which is clicked in `event.target`.

```
 $(.....).click(function(event){  ....  });
```

Another solution, more complex, but more flexible too, although you won't need it in this situation, is to use the `.bind` method and specify a data object

```
$(.....).bind('click', {whateverproperty: whatevervalue}, function(event){ ... });
```

In that case, you can reach `event.data.whateverproperty`, thus retrieving the value `whatevervalue`, allowing you to make more complex decisions.