# automatically add attributes to dynamically added html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to add `dir=auto` to several `ul` element that are being added dynamically when several events happen.

Since these events are not in my control (some are plug-ins, some are ajax results, etc) I don't want to add a line of code sporadically

how can I add `$("ul").attr("dir","auto")` in a way that any of the relevant elements will have the attributes once they are added to page?

Comment: a cross browser solution is difficult for this unless you are in control of the code which creates the new elements... in that case you can modify the code to add this attribute.... else another solution is to have a look at mutation events/observers.. but IE support will be a problem

Comment: I suggest you add a listener to the <ul> since <li> will be added dynamically (or only one time on load?) , once they are being modified or being added to, then filter/select them all and apply your .attr function. 
Check this out -> (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209304/jquery-binding-a-single-event-listener-that-can-handle-events-of-its-children)

Comment: delegate/on only work on events, and the list of events could be happen on any element and any user-driven or non-user-driven events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to add a listener to the document/dom to know once the`<ul>`  has been added dynamically, then check if that `<ul>` has been modified as well later after load *(to add other attri to them?)*.

The listener should work once `<ul>` is being modified or being added to the document, then filter/select the `<ul>` and apply your `.attr` function. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209304/jquery-binding-a-single-event-listener-that-can-handle-events-of-its-children) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener)

I've tested the code on my console for this SO page and it seems to be working. I'm using FF26, therefore something like this might help:

```
    //listen to parent to know if it's being modified. you can listen to <ul> if you want to check if it has modified if you want to do something with <li> for example. 
    $("#parentDiv").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
       //your code here       
        $("ul").attr("dir","auto");// to all <ul> in the page
        //or only filter ul that belongs to this div
       // this.find("ul").attr("dir","auto");
    });
```

**I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener)  answer has more accurate findings since (`DOMSubtreeModified`) seems to be deprecated (although it just worked fine).**

If the `<ul>` is going to be added later (unknown time) then in my opinion, you have two options:

1. Add the listener to `body` or parent div that holds the `<ul>` and monitor when `<ul>` is added then apply your attr.
2. Add a `setInterval` to keep checking if there is any `<ul>` in the page every *a few sec?*

I prefer option 1, because I've read that option 2 (using `setInterval`) might add some overhead. [Ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034107/does-javascript-setinterval-method-cause-memory-leak).

Comment: that seems to be in the direction to solve this, but what if the initial `ul` doesn't exist?

Comment: @NickGinanto I think you could set the handler for the parent element. and then target the `ul` children?

Comment: Hashem Qolami suggestion seems logical, check my edit.